# How to send parameters from a request (servlet) to another request (servlet) in Java?

Tags: javascript, java, url, server, request

```html
public String Home(HttpServletRequest request,
   HttpServletResponse response, HttpSession session) {
 
  String refer = request.getHeader("Referer");
         request.setAttribute("refer", refer);
  
 
  return "home/visit/editVisit";
 }
 
 public String Home2(HttpServletRequest request,
   HttpServletResponse response, HttpSession session) {
 
  String refer2 = request.getParameter("refer");
  
 
  return "home/visit/addVisit";
 }
```

In the first step, I get the function from one Controller to another Controller and since then the request changes in URL.

The new Controller page has several different functions.
I can catch the change there to know from which page I came by the line:
String refer = request.getHeader ("Refer");

But as I continue (by the buttons ...) to the next pages of the project. I don't have access to refer variable.

**How can I be constantly available to a variable that would please and not only refer to a specific JSP?**

I need quick help,

Thanks for every reply

Comment: Please share some sample code to show your approach.

Comment: I added.
I want in the Home2 function the refer2 variable gets the value of the refer variable in the Home function
Thanks